# How can I generate a list of the method names of a class in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript

Before upgrading to Angular 8, we could use the `prototype` property of an object, and it would give us a list like so:

```
class Foo {
    public bar(): boolean {
        return true
    }
}
expect(Object.keys(Foo.prototype)).to.equal(['bar'])
```

This works with the latest version of typescript, or Angular up to version 7.

*Something changed*, which I can NOT figure out, from Angular 7 -> 8, where the very same bit of code now returns:

```
expected [] to deeply equal [ 'bar' ]
```

`Object.prototype` does not function as expected anymore, and this problem pertains to the version of Angular we are using.

How can I generate a list of function names from any given class in Angular 8? Assuming you know *nothing* about the calss that is being passed into the function generating the names.

Comment: I believe it should be related to typescript version. can you check which versions of typescript you were using before and after update?

Comment: I was using TS 3.7.5 for both - pre and post Angular update